# A first chance exception occurred... and I don't know why

Tags: c#, debugging, windows-phone-7, mscorlib, first-chance-exception

Whenever I try to debug my Windows Phone 7 C# app, I get the following message in the Output window:

`A first chance exception of type 'System.OverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll`

`A first chance exception of type 'System.OverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll`

`A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.Phone.dll`

...And then, App.xaml.cs opens up in VS (still in debug mode, where I can't edit anything), and "System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();" is highlighted.

**Why is this happening, how can I fix it, and how can I prevent it in the future?**

Comment: Sounds to me like something in your App.xaml resources section is broken. We are going to need to see some code from App.xaml and App.xaml.cs to srtart with.

Comment: Okay, I found out how to fix it... but *why* the cryptic error messages? And *what* is a `System.OverflowException`?

Comment: WPF/XAML usually have poor error messages unfortunately. If the answer is generic enough, post it yourself. It is ok to answer your own questions and might help someone else.

Comment: Okay, I guess I'll post it-although I feel bad about answering my own question.

Comment: From JeffAtwood himself http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Why it happened:

I had an `image` that was used in MainPage.xaml. This image's source's `Copy to Output directory` property was set to `Do not copy`, and as a result, the image failed to load and the app crashed.

### How to Fix It:

Change the `image` in question's source's `Copy to Output directory` property to `Copy Always` from `Do not copy`.

### How it can be prevented:

Don't fiddle with my image's `Copy to Output directory` properties.

### ...and what caused the `System.OverflowException`:

My low disk space [I think] is what is causing the `System.OverflowException`s, because these continued to pop up in my Output window after I fixed the problem. Read up on `System.OverflowException`s [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y3d0kef1%28VS.80%29.aspx).