# WP8 InvalidOperation

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, invalidoperationexception

I am getting a:

`An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.Phone.ni.dll but was not handled in user code`

When I do:

```
ApplicationBarIconButton nextButton = new ApplicationBarIconButton(new Uri("/Images/next.png", UriKind.Relative));
nextButton.Text = "Next";

ApplicationBarIconButton backButton = new ApplicationBarIconButton(new Uri("/Images/back.png", UriKind.Relative));
nextButton.Text = "Previous";

ApplicationBar.Buttons.Add(nextButton);
ApplicationBar.Buttons.Add(backButton); //<---- Error when adding this
```

Can anyone see where I am going horribly wrong?

Comment: maybe a ressource-related problem like here? http://stackoverflow.com/a/6770469/594832

Comment: What happens if you add the back button first? That could narrow it down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you haven't set the `Text` property for the backbutton.

```
ApplicationBarIconButton backButton = new ApplicationBarIconButton(new Uri("/Images/back.png", UriKind.Relative));
backButton.Text = "Previous"; //<< you have nextButton.Text
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey the problem is your not actually setting the text for the back button, youve set nextButton.Text on both :)

Comment: ahhh damb beat me to it